# Maximize function does not evaluate

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Relatively new to Mathematica, sorry if a trivial question but I haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere. I'm trying to solve the following constrained maximization problem:

```
mu = 0.005;
sigma = 0.04;
muJ = -0.04;
sigmaJ = 0.80 / Sqrt[12];
WZero = 500;
A = 0.001;
WStar = -20;
h = 0.01;
p = .005;
K = 1;

S[disaster_, z_] := If[disaster == 1, Exp[muJ + sigmaJ z], Exp[mu + sigma z]]    

U = Expectation[WZero - \[Alpha] - \[Beta] P + \[Alpha] S[disaster, z] + \[Beta] Max[0, K - S[disaster, z]] - A/2 (WZero - \[Alpha] - \[Beta] P + \[Alpha] S[disaster, z] + \[Beta] Max[0, K - S[disaster, z]])^2, {z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], disaster \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p]}];

FOCU\[Alpha] := D[U, \[Alpha]];
FOCU\[Beta] := D[U, \[Beta]];

\[CapitalPi] = Expectation[\[Alpha]Hat (S[disaster, z] - 1) + \[Beta]Hat (Max[0, K - S[disaster, z]] - P), {z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], disaster \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p]}];

VaR[alpha_, beta_, price_] := Probability[alpha (S[disaster, z] - 1) + beta (Max[0, K - S[disaster, z]] - price) < WStar, {disaster \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p], z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}]

Maximize[{\[CapitalPi], VaR[\[Alpha]Hat, \[Beta]Hat, P] <= h, FOCU\[Alpha] == 0, FOCU\[Beta] == 0, \[Beta] + \[Beta]Hat == 0, \[Alpha]Hat <= 0, \[Beta]Hat <= 0, \[Alpha] >= 0, \[Beta] >= 0}, {P, \[Alpha]Hat, \[Beta]Hat, \[Alpha], \[Beta]}]
```

The final expression does not evaluate. This seems to be because of the function VaR, however I am unsure why this as as the function itself seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  I can't reproduce your issue.  I'm finding that just trying to evaluate U hangs.  Can you go into more details about what exactly you are expereince?

Comment: I scrape exactly your code down to just before `Maximize` and then I append your first list argument that you pass to `Maximize` and I evaluate all that, not trying to `Maximize` yet.. It takes a while but then I look at the result and I carefully compare that with the help page for `Maximize` to see if your code matches their examples. I'm not thinking I can see those agree. Then I try `Simplify` on the output and again try to compare with the help page. Can you see that your use agrees with the documentation?

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Not sure why the script hangs at U. I just copied into a new notebook after restarting Mathematica and it worked until the final Maximize call. Without knowing anything, possible that it's a version issue? I'm on Windows with Mathematica 10.

Comment: @Bill To the best of my understanding it agrees. First arg in the first list is the objective function and the remaining args are constraints. The second list consists of variables I want to maximize over. Best evidence is that this works without the call to the VaR function. Perhaps VaR is not consistent with the documentation, but I fail to see how.

Comment: Try changing your capitalized `K` to lowercase `k` (5 places).  When I tried it, your code evaluated without any problems in MMA 10.1 with Windows 7.  The uppercase version `K` has a special meaning in Mathematica.  Since all Mathematica variables and functions begin with uppercase letters we can avoid conflicts by using lowercase letters to begin all user variables.

Comment: I'm seeing your objective function, a comma, and then a big `Expectation` construct. Maybe that is what was confusing me. If in a fresh notebook I do nothing more than wrap `Simplify[]` around your first list argument to `Maximize` then it bails out the moment it gets there. That `Simplify` should have done nothing more than eliminate some redundant calculations. The docs for Maximize say the constraints should be a logical combination and you just have a comma separated list, but replacing commas with `&&`s doesn't change this. K doesn't change this for me. Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @LouisB Unfortunately changing the capitalization didn't work for me. Will be sure to use lowercase in future though. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will lead somewhere:  `soln = Solve[ {D[U,\[alpha]]==0, D[U,\[beta]]==0}, { \[alpha], \[beta]}]`  Then use `soln` to plot your $\Pi$ function to see if it is what you were expecting.

Comment: @LouisB That works as expected.